# Benefits of Memcache?

Tags: joomla-3.3.x

What is pros and cons of following code in configuration.php file?

```
public $memcache_persist = '1';
public $memcache_compress = '0';
public $memcache_server_host = 'localhost';
public $memcache_server_port = 'xxxx';
public $memcached_persist = '1';
public $memcached_compress = '0';
public $memcached_server_host = 'localhost';
public $memcached_server_port = 'xxxx';
public $session_memcache_server_host = 'localhost';
public $session_memcache_server_port = 'xxxx';
public $session_memcached_server_host = 'localhost';
public $session_memcached_server_port = 'xxxx';
```

I also have cache plugin enabled and as well as from global configuration.

```
public $caching = '1';
public $cache_handler = 'file';
public $cachetime = '720';
```

I am confused my hosting provider changed configuration file after switching to new server.

I just noticed and found memcache code in config file. What to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joomla has built-in support for Memcached. Memcached can be activated by editing your `configuration.php` file, or from cPanel on certain hosting companies.

Two variants of Memcached can be enabled:

**memcached**
Uses the Memcached server to store sessions in RAM. Requires the memcached PHP extension. The server is configured like this:

```
public $memcache_persist = '0';
public $memcache_compress = '0';
public $memcache_server_host = '127.0.0.1';
public $memcache_server_port = '11211';
```

**memcache**
Uses the Memcached server to store sessions in RAM. Requires the memcache PHP extension. Using this extension is not recommended, 'memcached' is better. The memcached server configuration for Joomla 2.5+ is identical to the 'memcached' option above.

**Note**
It looks like both these options are enabled in your `configuration.php` file (both **memchached** and **memcache**). If you changed hosting company recently, it is possible the the new hosting company added one of the options without removing the other.

It doesn't sound like a good idea to enable both, I would suggest removing **memcache** and see if that affects anything. But please correct me if I'm wrong (if it's OK to use both).

You can read more on Memcached here: http://www.memcached.org/