# Memcache settings for Joomla 3.3.6

Tags: joomla-3.3.x

I have placed these in my configuration file: but still cache handler is showing file instead of Memcache:

```
public $caching = '1';
public $cache_handler = 'memcached';
public $cachetime = '350';
public $session_handler = 'database';
public $memcache_persist = '1';
public $memcache_compress = '0';
public $memcache_server_host = 'localhost';
public $memcache_server_port = '11211';
public $memcached_persist = '1';
public $memcached_compress = '0';
public $memcached_server_host = 'localhost';
public $memcached_server_port = '11211';
public $session_memcache_server_host = 'localhost';
public $session_memcache_server_port = '11211';
public $session_memcached_server_host = 'localhost';
public $session_memcached_server_port = '11211';
```

My hosting provide said that memcache is installed. I would appreciate if someone can assist in this regard.

Comment: This answer might be of assistance: https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/5799/benefits-of-memcache/5800#5800

Answer (score 3):

More than likely your file is being set to "444" for permissions by your server. Right click the file in filezilla, or whatever you use, and set it to "644" and then save the config file and upload it again.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/supercacher/joomla_memcached.htm
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260258/how-to-use-memcached-with-joomla

those are good reference to start with ;)
Basically your configuration have some mistakes on it.

Comment: Can you point out what the mistakes are?

Answer (score 0):

public $caching = '1'; this should be 2. Or better yet, just copy the sample configuration on the site I've given and modify it according to your needs ;)

Comment: Instead of giving a separate answer it would be better to edit your previous answer with this new information. This is useful though, thankyou :)